# How to build a JSON tree structure using object dot notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, treeview, hierarchical-data

I have a collection of string literals in an array

```
var selected = ['a', 'b.c', 'b.c.d', 'b.c.d.e'];
```

How can I create a below JSON tree structure using JavaScript? Any help would be appreciable.

```
[{
    "title": "a",
    "id": "a"
  },
  {
    "title": "b",
    "id": "b",
    "children": [{
      "title": "c",
      "id": "c",
      "children": [{
          "title": "d",
          "id": "d",
          "children": [{
            "title": "e",
            "id": "e"
          }]
        },
        {
          "title": "f",
          "id": "f"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: Where are you getting the initial object from, it might be easier to change the way the data is returned rather than trying to manipulate the result.

Comment: you dont have any "f" in your original array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `recursion`

```js
var selected = ['a', 'b.c', 'b.c.d', 'b.c.d.e', 'b.c.g'];
var result = {};

selected.forEach(i =>
  i.split('.').reduce((result, val) => result[val] = result[val] || {}, result)
)

function toTree(o) {
  return Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => {
    let r = {'title': k, 'id': k, 'children': toTree(v)}
    !r.children.length && delete r.children
    return r
  })
}
result = toTree(result)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Well, i found one more issue with this solution. If i have 2 children for an attribute then it does not work. 
var selected = ['a', 'b.c', 'b.c.d', 'b.c.d.e', b.c.g];
In this case "c" should have 2 children (i.e [d,g]). But it is overwriting with the latest value. Kindly help.

Comment: @SaktiDash you can check the updated answer. I just check for available value `result[val] || {}`

Comment: Could you please help me on this query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882169/how-to-build-a-json-object-using-collection-of-dot-notation-strings-using-javasc?noredirect=1#comment105893405_59882169