# How to build a JSON object using collection of dot notation strings using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hierarchical-data

I have a collection of strings in an array. These strings are the JSON paths that i select from a checkbox tree.

var selected = ['a', 'b.c.0.d', 'b.c.1.d', 'b.c.0.e', 'b.c.1.e'];

I want to save it to the database with the real data given by the user. So i want to create a JSON object like following structure. It can be further nested.

```
    { 
       "a":5,
       "b":{ 
          "c":[ 
             { 
                "d":5,
                "e":5
             },
             { 
                "d":5,
                "e":5
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.