# Transform dot notation to a tree data form

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I have object oriented data in the form:

```
var alist = [
    'foo',
    'foo.lol1',
    'foo.lol2',
    'bar.lol1',
    'bar.barbar.kk',
    ...
]
```

which I would like to transform into a tree structure, to be able to serve them with a tree component (https://github.com/vinz3872/vuejs-tree in particular). The require form is the following:

```
var ok = [
    {
        text: "foo",
        state: { expanded: false },
        nodes: [
            {
                id: 1,
                path: "foo.lol1",
                text: "lol1",
                checkable: true,
                state: { checked: false },
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                path: "foo.lol2",
                text: "lol2",
                checkable: true,
                state: { checked: false },
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "bar",
        state: { expanded: false },
        nodes: [
            {
                id: 3,
                path: "bar.lol1",
                text: "lol1",
                checkable: true,
                state: { checked: false },
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "bar",
        state: { expanded: false },
        nodes: [
            {
                id: 3,
                path: "bar.lol1",
                text: "lol1",
                checkable: true,
                state: { checked: false },
            },
            {
                text: "barbar",
                state: { expanded: false },
                nodes: [
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        path: "bar.barbar.kk",
                        text: "kk",
                        checkable: true,
                        state: { checked: false },
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I am aware that I should use recursion and I have tried all relevan posts in stackoverflow, i.e. [How to build a JSON tree structure using object dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714880/how-to-build-a-json-tree-structure-using-object-dot-notation).
My main problem is that I have to somehow preserve the information of the full path to the leaves of the tree. As a newbie in js I lost myself in counters and callback for days without any luck.
I would appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could use `forEach` then split each string into array and then use `reduce` on that. Then you build nested object where the keys are current paths and also ad to result array.

```js
var alist = [
  'foo',
  'foo.lol1',
  'foo.lol2',
  'bar.lol1',
  'bar.barbar.kk',
]

const result = []
const levels = {
  result
}

let prev = ''
let id = 1

alist.forEach(str => {
  str.split('.').reduce((r, text, i, arr) => {
    const path = prev += (prev.length ? '.' : '') + text

    if (!r[path]) {
      r[path] = {result: []}
      
      const obj = {
        id: id++,
        text,
      }
      
      if (i === 0) {
        obj.state = {expanded: false}
      } else {
        obj.state = {checked: false}
        obj.checkable = true
        obj.path = path
      }
      
      obj.nodes = r[path].result
      r.result.push(obj)
    }

    if (i === arr.length - 1) {
      prev = ''
    }

    return r[path]
  }, levels)
})


console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Nenad! I appreciate it. Unfortunately, this is a partial solution as there is a need for a distinction between leefs and nonleefs that is not covered. Scott's answer helped me cover it tho. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was easiest to do this transformation in two steps.  The first converts your input into this format:

```js
{
  foo: {
    lol1: {}, 
    lol2: {}
  },
  bar: {
    barbar: {
      kk: {}
    }, 
    lol1: {}
  }, 
}
```

The second uses just this format to create your desired structure.  This has two advantages.  First, I have tools lying around that make it easy to create this structure from your input.  Second, this structure embeds enough information to create your output, with only one branching construct: whether the value at a path is an empty object or has properties.  This makes the generation code relatively simple:

```js
const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const reformat = (o, path = [], nextId = ((id) => () => String (++ id)) (0)) =>
  Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => Object .entries (v) .length > 0
    ? {text: k, state: {exapanded: false}, nodes: reformat (v, [...path, k], nextId)}
    : {id: nextId (), path: [...path, k] .join('.'), text: k, checkable: false, state: {checked: false}}
  )

const transform = (pathTokens) =>
  reformat (pathTokens
    .map (s => s .split ('.'))
    .reduce ((a, path) => setPath (path) ({}) (a), {})
  )


const alist = ['foo', 'foo.lol1', 'foo.lol2', 'bar.lol1', 'bar.barbar.kk']

console .log (transform (alist))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start with `setPath`, which takes a path, in a format such as `['bar', 'barbar', 'kk']`, the value to set at that path, and an object to shallow clone with this new property along that path.  Thus `setPath (['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) (42) ({foo: {qux: 7}, corge: 6})` yields `{foo: {qux: 7, bar: {baz: 42}}, corge: 6}`.  (There's a little more in this reusable function to also handle array indices instead of string object paths, but we can't reach that from this input format.)

Then we have `reformat`, which does the format conversion.  It simply builds a different input object based upon whether the input value is an empty object.

Finally, `transform` maps a splitting function over your input array to get the path structure needed for `setPath`, folds the results into an initially empty object by setting every path value to an empty object, yielding our intermediate format, which we then pas to `reformat`.

There is one thing I really don't like here, and that is the `nextId` function, which is a stateful function.  We could just have easily used a generator function, but whatever we do here, we're using state to build this output and that bothers me.  If someone has a cleaner suggestion for this, I'd love to hear it.